# First frames of video from Rasp Pi camera have a high exposure

Tags: raspicam, video

When I record video using the v1 of the Rasp Pi Noir camera the first few frames/second have a very high exposure (very bright) and then it settles down to a reasonable exposure setting. Because the videos are taken throughout the day I think I need to rely on auto exposure. I'm looking for a way to avoid having these very bright/washed out frames at the beginning. The command I'm using to capture the video is

```
raspivid -o test.h264 -t 200000 -fps 2 -w 1280 -h 720
```

I use MP4Box to make the video into an MP4 file. If it isn't possible to avoid capturing these washed-out frames is there a way to trim them out after capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to CoderMike's suggestion to use the PiCamera library I've come up with what seems to be a working solution. My first few attempts didn't work (e.g. doing a sleep right before calling start_recording). The solution below records two videos. The first, trash.h264, is a throw away file that captures a few seconds at 15 fps. The second video, test.h264, is the one I want. Testing on a bright day today shows that trash.h264 is blown out but test.h264 is properly exposed.

```
from time import sleep
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
camera.framerate = 15
# First few seconds are blown out as auto-exposure kicks in, so record a dummy first.
camera.start_recording('trash.h264')
camera.wait_recording(5)
camera.stop_recording()

camera.framerate = 2
camera.start_recording('test.h264')
camera.wait_recording(140)
camera.stop_recording()
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. This will finish the question and it will not pop up again year by year.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the initial washed out frames are the camera judging the exposure. The Pi camera modules automatically manage the exposure.

> The camera must produce preview frames even if these aren't required for display, as they're used for calculating exposure and white balance settings

[Pi Camera Modules](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md)

In terms of the removing them there will be a way to do it automatically I'm sure but I wouldn't know where to start I'm afraid. The only thing I can suggest would be removing them in a video editor.

Comment: Yes, I understand judging the exposure. To be clear I need a programmatic way to remove those frames if I can't avoid them. For my project running a video editor with a GUI won't help.

Comment: How about using some python code and the PiCamera library. Use start_preview a few seconds before start_recording may avoid the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the library. It was easy to create something to try to work around this issue. Unfortunately today there is a heavy overcast and rain so I can't be sure it is working. Once there is a sunny day if it looks good I'll post a code sample.